# iMac 27 late 2009 - Grey screen shows at startup on yosemite

Tags: imac, macos, hardware, gpu

iMac screen stuck while watching youtube. 
[image]

After restart system stuck on grey screen :( 
[image]
[image]

**Tried All these given below**

- Did reset PRAM
- Did Hard Drive Verify
- Re-install Yosemite
- Clean install Yosemite
- Working in safemode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Issue on my old iMac - it turned out to be defective Memory of the Graphics Card (due to overheating).

I changed the Graphics Card and fixed the problem. There is a very well written tutorial on how to change the Card on [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2309+or+2374+Graphics+Card+Replacement/9553). The only problem would be to find a replacement Card - i paid about 360$ for mine.

Comment: Before repairing the mac, bring it to an apple authorised service provider to verify that it is the memory of the graphics card.